# Converting date from 3 digit format to Julian date in R or excel

Tags: r, excel, date

I currently have dates in the format mdd (single or double digit month and double digit day), with the year in a separate column.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
Year Date
1996 921
1996 923
1996 1001
1996 1127
1997 502
```

I would like to combine these and convert them to julian dates. Can anyone help me with this? I don't know why this data has been collected in such an awkward format.

Thank you so much in advance for your help - code for R or excel will be fine!

Comment: Hmm, I thought you wanted an `r` answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
as.POSIXlt(sprintf('%04d%04d', df1$Year, df1$Date),
         format ='%Y%m%d')$yday
#[1] 264 266 274 331 121
```

Answer (score 2):

In Excel

```
=DATE(A2,INT(B2/100),MOD(B2,100))
```

Where the year is in A2 and the month/day in B2.